# useCallback + setState. Using previous state value vs passing the state as a dependency

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, rerender

So the task is:

> 1. When you click on the "Increase temperature by 1 degree" button,
>    the temperature increased
> 2. The TempDisplay component should not be rerendered when clicking on
>    the "Increase by 10 seconds" button

My solutions:

```
useCallback(() => (setTemp(temp+1)),[temp])
```

and

```
useCallback(() => (setTemp(temp=>temp+1)),[])
```

Is any of this solutions wrong and what's the difference? Or both can be used?

Full code:

```
export const App = () => {
    const [temp, setTemp] = useState(10)
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(100)

    const increaseSeconds = () => setSeconds(seconds + 10)

    const increaseTemp = XXX here we need to define the function XXX

    return <>
        <TempDisplay temp={temp} increaseTemp={increaseTemp}/>

        <div>
            <b>Seconds :</b> {seconds} с
            <button style={{marginLeft: '15px'}}
                    onClick={increaseSeconds}>
                Increase by 10
            </button>
        </div>
    </>
}
const TempDisplay = React.memo((props: any) => {
    console.log('Render TempDisplay')
    return (
        <div style={{marginBottom: '15px'}}
             onClick={props.reset}>
            <b>Temperature:</b> {props.temp} &#176;
            <button style={{marginLeft: '15px'}}
                    onClick={props.increaseTemp}>
                Increase temperature by 1
            </button>
        </div>
    )
})
```

Comment: The first creates a function with stable identity. The second creates a function whose identity changes every time the state changes.

Comment: @jsejcksn On the contrary, the second one gets created and never changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you passed the `[]` as a callback dependency, the callback function will not get recreated even if the dependency value gets updated.

Hence, you will not get updated values for `temp` at the time callback function get called

Comment: Thank you, Sachila! In this case is there any difference between useCallback(() => (setTemp(temp+1)),[temp])  and  useCallback(() => (setTemp(temp=>temp+1)),[temp])? As we get the actual temp every time it changes as a dependency? Or am I missing some basics about state in general?

Comment: The first one use the setState in an asynchronous way.  That means after calling setTemp the temp variable is not immediately changed. so if you want to perform an action immediately after setting state on a state variable and then return a result,then second approach can be used.